# Silent Install Switches for Adobe Camera RAW 6.7

Tags: windows-7, installation, photoshop-cs5, camera-raw

What are the silent install switches for the Adobe Photoshop Camera RAW 6.7 update?

I tried `--mode=silent` but that wasn't exactly silent, the install went through without intervention from me, but the dialog was displayed the whole time and I still had to click "OK" at the end of the install.

I have also tried `-verysilent` and `-silent`, they do the same thing as `--mode=silent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I guess I figured this out.

I was running `AdobePatchInstaller.exe --mode=silent` straight from `cmd.exe`. When I would do this, I would receive a window with progress and a final "OK" button, as I mentioned above.

However, when I ran `start /wait AdobePatchInstaller.exe --mode=silent` from the command line, much like I would in a batch file, the patch seemed to install silently without fail.

Not sure I understand the difference, but it worked fine just the same.